# Why is this combined SORTYBY,FILTER,SEQUENCE,INDEX,COUNTIF formula sorting partially?

Tags: sorting, excel-formula, filtered-index

I have formula calculated values in columns H:O (The number of rows adjust dynamically based on how many filtered values are in columns A:G. The headers end on Row 2)

The calculations in columns H:O tell whether or not the status of something is due, upcoming, or compliant based on hours. And other relevant data. Column O ranks these values with a number on what is most overdue.

These work perfectly.

Below is a filtered array that only displays Due items and it supposed to rank them in Ascending order from 1 to the lowest number (This rank is listed in value O). But it only partially sorts this, like 3,6,9,11,2. etc.

```
=SORTBY(FILTER(INDEX($A:$O,SEQUENCE(ROWS($A:$O)),{6,7,3,11,15}),$N:$N="DUE"),INDEX($O:$O,SEQUENCE(COUNTIF($N:$N,"DUE"))),1)
```

I did try pasting as values and doing a simplier formula since it was only dealing with values and not a filtered range and it sorted correctly. I tried adjusting the values in Column O to be General, number, text, etc, and it still sorted wonky.

Comment: That whole `INDEX($O:$O,SEQUENCE(COUNTIF($N:$N,"DUE")))` is not returning what you think it is.  `=SORT(FILTER(INDEX($A:$O,SEQUENCE(ROWS($A:$O)),{6,7,3,11,15}),$N:$N="DUE"),5,1)`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya you are correct. As Scott Craner suggested it wasn't returning the proper array.  I added SMALL(IF(...), SEQUENCE(COUNTIF)) to the formula to create an Array of row numbers based on the number of "DUE" rows and then used small to rank it properly. Thank you fellas!

Comment: That is a lot of unnecessary work to sort on the O column

Answer (score 1):

`INDEX($O:$O,SEQUENCE(COUNTIF($N:$N,"DUE")))` is not returning the same rows as `FILTER(INDEX($A:$O,SEQUENCE(ROWS($A:$O)),{6,7,3,11,15}),$N:$N="DUE")`

It is returning the top cells in column O totaling the number of cells in the whole N column that = `DUE`.  IE if there are 10 cell that = `DUE` then it is returning `O1:O10` not the ones that are joining the DUE:

Instead use SORT and just dictate the 5th column of your return:

```
=SORT(FILTER(INDEX($A:$O,SEQUENCE(ROWS($A:$O)),{6,7,3,11,15}),$N:$N="DUE"),5,1)
```

if you really want to use SORTBY then use a second FILTER:

```
=SORTBY(FILTER(INDEX($A:$O,SEQUENCE(ROWS($A:$O)),{6,7,3,11,15}),$N:$N="DUE"),FILTER($O:$O,$N:$N="DUE"),1)
```

But that is doing extra unneeded calculations.